# Rewrite all article pictures to link to file

Tags: images, attachments

I got a wordpress blog with thousands of articles.

The problem: I want to use a lightbox plugin(http://wordpress.org/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) but in order to work the pictures in an article have to link to the file. At the moment all pictures link to the attachment page.

I already changed image_default_link_type to file, but that only applies to new articles of course.

What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Would it work if you redirected the attachment pages to the actual image files?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm thinking about a content filter at the moment which replaces every link to an attachment page with the link to the file.